# Добавление места на сервер с СУБД Oracle для выполнения бэкапов

Tags: windows, oracle, резервное-копирование, storage

Есть Windows Server 2016 с установленной Oracle DB 11.0.2.4.
Сама СУБД уже занимает практически 60% от 9ТБ плюс бэкапы БД на 30%.
Пробовал выполнять сетевые бэкапы на удаленный хост, но в таком случае скорость выполнения бэкапа упирается в ограничения файловой системы(в десятки раз медленнее чем на локальные диски). 
Так же при этом варианте не возможно параллелить выполнение бэкапов. 
Подскажите, как можно в таком случае "добавить" места на сервер, что бы выполнять бэкапы без потери скорости?
Есть StoreOnce и две хранилки, но как их презентовать серверу не понимаю.

Comment: Ну а делать бэкап локально, переливать состояние на удалённый хост и удалять локальную копию для освобождения места - не?

Comment: Привет. Локально бэкап уже не будет помещается через пару месяцев. Вопрос именно в том, как можно добавить место на физический сервер. Примеры удачных реализаций.

Comment: А, ты начал писать камент после прочтения слова "локально". Прочти, пожалуйста, всё что я написал.

Comment: Поясни пожалуйста, что ты имеешь ввиду под этой схемой?

Comment: Я имею ввиду ровно то, что написал. Если ты захочешь написать "я ничего не понял", без уточнения конкретных мест - ну значит скорее всего, будешь ждать тех, кто напишет более понятно.